# Symfony $controller->getUser() alternative in non-secured areas?

Tags: security, symfony, routes, controller

My current project almost all routes are protected by a `form_login`.

Two routes `/login` and `/user/forgot_password` should remain unprotected to be accessible by non-authenticated users.
Is there any way I can prevent access of authenticated users to this routes?

In my controller I can check for `$this->getUser()` however in non-secured areas the `security.context` is not filled with the corresponding data.

Configuration (security.yml):

```
security:
    firewalls:
        nonsecured:
            pattern:  ^/(login|user/forgot_password)$
            security: false
        secured:
            pattern:  ^/
            # ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the current user information without an active firewall. Here's how you can solve the problem:

- Remove the `nonsecured` firewall so that the whole app is covered by an active firewall,
- Enable anonymous access by adding `anonymous: ~` to the `secured` firewall,
- Use access control to decide who can get where:

  ```
  access_control:
      - { path: ^/login,                roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      - { path: ^/user/forgot-password, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
      - { path: ^/,                     roles: ROLE_USER }
  ```

To prevent access to `/login` and `/user/forgot-password` for authenticated users, you have at least these two options:

- Check for the user in the controllers — the way you suggested, or
- Use `JMSSecurityExtraBundle`'s expressions:

  ```
  access_control:
      - { path: ^/login,                access: 'isAnonymous()' }
      - { path: ^/user/forgot-password, access: 'isAnonymous()' }
      - { path: ^/,                     access: 'isAuthenticated()' }
  ```

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm (as your BCrypt bundle does too ;))